# Optional Protocol Requirements, I Can't Get It To Work

Tags: swift, protocols, option-type

I am working on one of the examples in *The Swift Programming Language* book related to Optional Protocol Requirements. I have a problem in the following code.

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol CounterDataSource {
    optional func incrementForCount(count: Int) -> Int
    optional var fixedIncrement: Int { get }
}

@objc class Counter {
    var count = 0
    var dataSource: CounterDataSource?
    func increment() {
        if let amount = dataSource?.incrementForCount?(count) {
            count += amount
        } else if let amount = dataSource?.fixedIncrement {
            count += amount
        }
    }
}

class ThreeSource: CounterDataSource {
    var fixedIncrement = 3
}

var counter = Counter()
counter.dataSource = ThreeSource()

for _ in 1...4 {
    counter.increment()
    println(counter.count)
}
```

Shouldn't this work? The `println()` continuously outputs 0, when it should be incrementing by 3s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@objc protocol` requires `@objc` implementation.

In your case:

```
class ThreeSource: CounterDataSource {
    @objc var fixedIncrement = 3
//  ^^^^^ YOU NEED THIS!
}
```

without it, Objective-C runtime can't find the property.